# Save theme change with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a site in which i can change theme by clicking on a color like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class='red'></span>
        <span class='orange'></span>
        <span class='green'></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This part works just fine, but... When refreshing page it goes back to normal, so.

I want to save the color in my DB using jQuery Ajax, but not sure how to send the color onclick to my jQuery function?

```
$(function() {
    $('.themechange').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "http://mydomain.com/updatetheme.php",
           data: "color=somecolor",
           success: function(msg){
             alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
           }
         });
    });
});
```

I don't know how to do this and are hoping for help :-)

Comment: can you show us your `.themechange` html ..what is that ??

Comment: .themechange is nothing. Just something I put in. I don't know what to put here?

Comment: Add class `themechange` to your span tags like `class='red themechange'` and also add an `id` for each of them with their proper name like `id = "red"` then in the `data` property of jquery ajax write `data: "color=" + $(this).attr('id'),`. You're set to go!

Comment: Yes!!! Did the job ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
   <ul>
        <li>
            <span class='red  themechange' data-color='red'></span>
            <span class='orange themechange'  data-color='orange'></span>
            <span class='green themechange' data-color='green '></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.themechange').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "http://mydomain.com/updatetheme.php",
           data: "color=" + $(this).data('color'),
           success: function(msg){
             alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
           }
         });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get color value and call ajax on click event

http://jsfiddle.net/ZmbbA/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").click(function(){

        alert('Here ajax happens with color: ' + $(this).attr("class"));
    /*
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://mydomain.com/updatetheme.php",
        data: { color: $(this).attr("class") }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
    */
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

get same class for your list elements:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class='themechange' data-color='red'></span>
        <span class='themechange'  data-color='orange'></span>
        <span class='themechange' data-color='green '></span>
    </li>
</ul>

(function() {
$('.themechange').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://mydomain.com/updatetheme.php",
       data: "color=" + $(this).attr('data-color'),
       success: function(msg){
         alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
       }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

See which class is adding when you are changing the theme. It may add to your page's body. If so then store that class into jQuery cookies or you can use php session/cookies [via ajax]. Then add php session/cookie variable to body. Like this `<body class="<?php echo $_SESSION['themeName'] ?>">`